# When is the woodcutter worth buying in Dominion?

Tags: dominion

So far I've found every card in Dominion has its own niche, but the woodcutter's seems to be exceptionally small. I only buy 1 or 2 if its the only card that gives +buys, otherwise a silver is better 99.9% of the time.

Am I missing a key factor of the woodcutter? Is this the best way to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The utility depends entirely upon what's been placed into the initial setup. If it's the only 3-cost card, it's pretty useful.

Remember: some people play with random card selection.

Also, it's a +2 coin and +1 buy action. Silver is a +2 coin, but costs no action. So it's essentially a silver that trades an action for a second buy. Which is wonderful when trying to buy out the villages and other cheap cards.

If your options include villages and mines, having a short deck with village, mine and woodcutter allows grabbing extra copper to convert to silver...

Comment: Even if there was a mine available I doubt I'd buy copper to convert it to silver unless I had a very strong reason to risk clogging my deck. Maybe if I had several mines and absolutely no silver or copper whatsoever. I completely agree with the rest though. :D

Comment: I agree - if I've already mined my Copper into 7 Silver, I probably don't even want more Silver (from Copper) anyway!

Comment: If you're mostly silver, odds are the extra buy already goes to another mine or village...

Comment: Don't forget that Mine is a lot more useful if you have Prosperity, which also has Platinum and 8 specialty treasures.  Upgrading a Gold to a Platinum increases its value by $2 instead of $1.

Answer (score 8):

I recommend the insightful writeup at the [Dominion Strategy](http://dominionstrategy.com/2010/12/10/dominion-woodcutter/) blog.

It boils down to mostly what you said: +Buy can certainly be very key, so if Woodcutter is the only way to get it, Woodcutter is useful.  It also works well with Gardens, but in the long run it's just one of the least useful cards in the base set.

Answer (score 2):

The time woodcutter stands out best is if there is a thief in play.  You now have almost a silver that cannot be stolen.
When i play dominion i keep a mental count of how many extra actions i have vs action cards in my deck.  If the action number gets high woodcutters become a much better card

Comment: Even in the Thief case, Woodcutter is one of the WORST +$2 cards in Dominion, though.

Comment: Woodcutter shines even more against Pirate Ships... and if you're playing with Seaside maybe you have one of those fantastic villages (Native or Fishing) which could both (a) make you want more buys and (b) make you not mind spending an action.